# Use iframe elements layered under another iframe

Tags: html, iframe, click, layer

I have 2 iframes layered one above the other.

I need to click some button in the iframe with lower z- index.

Answer (score 0):

So e.g. iframe A has `z-index: 5` and iframe B has `z-index: 6`. And B covers A. Am I right? I'm not sure about this case, but maybe you can just go with `:hover` CSS selector to manipulate those indexes. Here is the example with divs (hard to put src in online editors), but it should also work with iframes: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1zj6dn7q/1/).

Comment: Thanks Mate for the great effort, my case is same but an iframes instead.

Comment: I see, but it shouldn't be a problem with similar code structure. It's hard to use iframes with external src in online editors, so modified example: https://jsfiddle.net/1zj6dn7q/2/. And the last one: https://jsfiddle.net/1zj6dn7q/4/.

Comment: I have the above frame is transparent that I can see the whole elements of the lowered frame. But, unable to click any! As it looks like a glass board above that preventing interact with the lowered frame. An important thing that I have the frames with same dimentions, I no way can use hover to switch in between. I need all frames elements accessible at the same time. Hope this clarifies my point.

Comment: I can't imagine this idea to myself. Upper iframe is like a glass, isn't it? Has it something inside or can it be replaced with a proper CSS style? And you want to be able to click button below this glass, don't you?

Comment: Exactly, it's content comes from another app deployed on same server.

Comment: Hard to do this in pure HTML and CSS. My current idea: https://jsfiddle.net/1zj6dn7q/6/. Check it and translate divs to iframes by yourself. I know this is not perfect, but maybe it's closer to your expectations.